# Error when using slick code generator on postgres with uuid_generate_v4()

Tags: postgresql, scala, jdbc, sbt, slick

I'm running into an error when I use the slick code generator on an existing postgres 9.3 database that uses uuid_generate_v4() to auto-generate IDs for tables.  I'm just getting started with slick and so I'm not sure yet if it's an issue with my code, my schema, with slick itself, or if this scenario is even supported yet.

As an example, I have columns that were created with statements like this:

```
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
```

When I run the slick code generator with `sbt run`, I get the error listed below.  This error makes the code generator fail and thus no code is generated.

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: uuid_generate_v4()
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: uuid_generate_v4()
    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
    at slick.driver.PostgresDriver$ModelBuilder$$anon$2$$anonfun$default$1.applyOrElse(PostgresDriver.scala:75)
    at slick.driver.PostgresDriver$ModelBuilder$$anon$2$$anonfun$default$1.applyOrElse(PostgresDriver.scala:65)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:223)
    at scala.PartialFunction$Lifted.apply(PartialFunction.scala:219)
    at scala.Option.collect(Option.scala:282)
    at slick.driver.PostgresDriver$ModelBuilder$$anon$2.default(PostgresDriver.scala:65)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ColumnBuilder$$anonfun$defaultColumnOption$3.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:254)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ColumnBuilder$$anonfun$defaultColumnOption$3.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:254)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ColumnBuilder.defaultColumnOption(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:253)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ColumnBuilder.convenientDefault(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:263)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ColumnBuilder.model(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:281)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder$$anonfun$columns$1.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:162)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder$$anonfun$columns$1.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:162)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.columns$lzycompute(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:162)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.columns(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:162)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.columnsByName$lzycompute(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:164)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.columnsByName(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:164)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$ForeignKeyBuilder.buildModel(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:314)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder$$anonfun$buildForeignKeys$1.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:169)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder$$anonfun$buildForeignKeys$1.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:169)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.buildForeignKeys(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:169)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$TableBuilder.buildModel(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:160)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$$anonfun$buildModel$3$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:94)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$$anonfun$buildModel$3$$anonfun$apply$17.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:94)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$$anonfun$buildModel$3.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:94)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder$$anonfun$buildModel$3.apply(JdbcModelBuilder.scala:91)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:43)
    at slick.dbio.DBIOAction$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DBIOAction.scala:43)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anonfun$runInContext$1.apply(DatabaseComponent.scala:146)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1943)
    at sbt.BuildCommon$$anonfun$toError$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1943)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at sbt.BuildCommon$class.toError(Defaults.scala:1943)
    at sbt.package$.toError(package.scala:4)
    at $4f4c3fbf06757612bb06$$anonfun$slickCodeGenTask$1.apply(build.sbt:27)
    at $4f4c3fbf06757612bb06$$anonfun$slickCodeGenTask$1.apply(build.sbt:19)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:35)
    at scala.Function4$$anonfun$tupled$1.apply(Function4.scala:34)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:managedSources) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Here are the details of my sbt project ...

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version = 0.13.8
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := "slick_gen_schema_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1103-jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.11" % "3.0.2",
  "com.typesafe.slick" % "slick-codegen_2.11" % "3.0.2"
)

slick <<= slickCodeGenTask

sourceGenerators in Compile <+= slickCodeGenTask

lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
  val outputDir = (dir / "main/slick").getPath
  val username = "postgres"
  val password = "postgres"
  val url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.0.11.13:5432/example"
  val jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  val slickDriver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver"
  val pkg = "dao"
  toError(r.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, username, password), s.log))
  val fname = outputDir + "/dao/Tables.scala"
  Seq(file(fname))
}
```

What is the right way to use the slick code generator in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Slick bug, which was fixed in Slick master (https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1472).

Until Slick 3.2 comes out, you could work around the issue by changing your schema to not have a functional default.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the update.  I don't necessarily need the workaround right now so I'll keep tabs on slick 3.2.